# Sound preferences vanished

Tags: sound, menu

Some time ago, I realized that the "Sound Preferences..." button (the one that shows up when clicking on the sound icon) stop working. When I click on it, nothing happens anymore.

I proceeded to search for the sound options on "Administration" and "Preferences" sub-menus on System menu. And then I understood what happened: It simply vanished for some uncanny reason.

So now I need to know if there is a way to reinstall it through apt-get or if not, know what is the source package to build it from the source.